# How to drag-n-drop TableHeaderColumn from material UI with react-dnd?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-dnd

How to apply drag-n-drop functionality from [react-dnd](https://github.com/gaearon/react-dnd) library to [TableHeaderColumn component from material ui](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/table)

The problem is **react-dnd does not support custom tags** and suggests to wrap TableHeaderColumn in div but **material ui does not allow to wrap** table component in any tag :(

I can't find any examples by this theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And the answer is - there are no way to do it with react-dnd, at least for this moment.
So I've ended up using [react-sortable-hoc](http://clauderic.github.io/react-sortable-hoc/#/basic-configuration/basic-usage?_k=5cgrgl) which works as expected in pair with material UI table elements.

Comment: Can you provede an example? React-sortable-hoc with material-ui doesn't work for me.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: Would also like to see an example of  react-sortable + material ui

Comment: probably too late for the previous commenters, but google still lead me here. This is a good library for this purpose, so here's an example https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-q9313?file=/demo.js

Comment: @Bastiat do you have links for sorting the rows as well?

Comment: @blah updated the same link. This is the basis of how I typically do table sorting, you see the sortFunc on the column definition and then a function that handles the sorting and allows custom sorting per column/based on different data types. Related to this library, notice the distance prop on the sortable header. That keeps the sort from starting immediately which allows the onClick to be registered for row purposes rather than the mousedown eating the event for column sort